# Can you assign a variable name to the thing a pointer is pointing at, after the pointer has been allocated?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, lvalue

Say I have some code where I have a variable a and I allocate a pointer to point to `a`:

```
int a = 5;
int* ptr = &a;
```

However, after this, I want to give the memory location that variable `a` occupies the name `b`.

```
int b = a;  // doesn't work, because it only copies the value
&b = ptr;   // doesn't work, not an assignable value

ptr = &b;   // doesn't work, this moves the pointer to point to b
            // instead of renaming the location that ptr already pointed to
```

Is this possible? (There's no good reason for doing this - just curious.)

--
Edit: This question is not about the differences between pointers and references, but rather how to achieve a goal through using them, and thus is not a duplicate of "what is the difference between references and pointers?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to give the memory location that variable "a" occupies the name "b"

What you want is reference, if I understand your question correctly.

```
int& b = a;       // b is an alias of a
assert(&a == &b); // the same memory location

b = 6;            // the value of both a and b changed to 6
```

Answer (score 1):

`int& b = a` binds the integer reference `a` to `b`. The address of the variable `a` is completely **unmodified**.
It simply means that all uses (references) of a actually use the value assigned to `b`.

Answer (score 0):

No, assigning (or *renaming*) a *variable name (identifier)* is not possible.

However, if you're interested, you can always to

```
int * b;
b = &a;
```

where `b` *points to* the variable `a`. Changes made to `*b` will *reflect* to `a` and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple pointers pointing to the same place:

```
int i = 10;
int* p1 = &i;
int* p2 = &i;
int* p3 = p2;
```

As you have already discovered, you cant say `&b = ptr;`